# Change color beamer bottom

Tags: beamer

I am trying to change all the beamer hyperlink bottoms fill in, that is not have a white letters and blue fill in but only blue letters and don't know how to do this.

Comment: This problem could use some more details of where the actual error is in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can control the colour of beamer buttons via the two colours `button` and `button border`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{button}{bg=red,fg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{button border}{fg=green}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item<1-> First item.
  \item<2-> Second item.
  \item<3-> Third item.
  \end{itemize}
  \hyperlink{jumptosecond}{\beamergotobutton{Jump to second slide}}
  \hypertarget<2>{jumptosecond}{}
\end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]